# How to access in base class method a certain class attributes all derived classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
class C:
    keys = {1}
    def get_keys(self):
        return C.keys + self...    # ???
class D(C):
    keys = {2,3}
class E(D):
    keys = {4,5}
```

I'd like to access and gather together all `keys` contents from all derived classes (from `self.__class__` to `C`) without the need of adding any additional code to any derived class.
In this example, I'd like `E().get_keys()` to return `{1,2,3,4,5}`.
I suppose it should be feasible starting through `self`, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to traverse the whole inheritance chain.
Could anyone help?

Comment: what precisely is the behavior you want when you call `C().get_keys()`, `D().get_keys()`, and `E.get_keys()`? The same output?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, YES, the same. And don't want to override get_keys()

Comment: Then I guess you can search through `type(self).__subclasses__()`

Answer (score 2):

Have each class add its keys to the set inherited from the parent. Then use `self.keys` in the method.

```
class C:
    keys = {1}
    def get_keys(self):
        return self.keys

class D(C):
    keys = C.keys | {2,3}

class E(D):
    keys = D.keys | {4,5}
```

Comment: Could be, but it would be nicer to not have to merge sets in each child class.